# Geth error: flag provided but not defined

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining, private-blockchain, nodes

Geth version

> 

```
 Geth
Version: 1.10.20-stable
Git Commit: 8f2416a89a3def6ec2c749d5afafbf2c9a18e3c8
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.18.1
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
```

Error:

```
flag provided but not defined: -identification
```

My .sh file

```
geth --identification "miner1" --networkid 42 --mine --minerthreads 2 --datadir "~/RPI/miner1" --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8042" --port "30303" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi db,eth,web,web3,private,miner,admin,txpool,debug,personal,net --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock 0 --password ~/RPI/password.sec --ipcpath "~/.ethereum/geth.ipc"
```

Even if I remove identification the error changes to:

```
flag provided but not defined: -networkid
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer found!

So each version of geth has some slightly different commands. For example `rpc` is now `http`.

I strongly recommend using `geth help`, as it will provide you with the list of all the commands that you may need for the version installed. Then you can check what you need and which command needs replacement.